# Adding an entry at the front of a linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Welp I have finally reached pointers after a very long time.  I understand my programs will gain elegance and power.  Sadly, my understanding seems to be lacking.  I am working in Kochan's programming in C 4th edition, and this is exercise 10.3.  I am to add an entry to the beginning of the linked list, however what I think should work does not work.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

struct entry
  {
      int      value;
      struct entry *next;
  };
                        //n0_1              list_pointer
void insertEntry(struct entry *what, struct entry *where)
{
    what->next = where->next;
    where->next = what;
}

int main (void)
{

struct entry n1, n2, n3, n4, n5,n0_1, n2_3, n3_4, n4_5;

struct entry *list_pointer = &n1;

  n1.value = 100;
  n2.value = 200;
  n3.value = 300;
  n4.value = 400;
  n5.value = 500;

  n1.next = &n2;
  n2.next = &n3;
  n3.next = &n4;
  n4.next = &n5;
  n5.next = (struct entry*)0;

  n0_1.value = 50;
  n2_3.value = 250;
  n3_4.value = 350;
  n4_5.value = 450;

  insertEntry(&n0_1, list_pointer);
  insertEntry(&n3_4, &n3);
  insertEntry(&n4_5, &n4);


  while (list_pointer != (struct entry *)0){
    printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
    list_pointer = list_pointer->next;

  }


  return 0;
}
```

So i break down what is happening as follows-

```
n0_1.next = List_pointer.next    //ok n0_1.next points to whatever the list pointer was.  
list_pointer.next = n0_1     //doesn't that make list pointer point to n0_1?
```

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks in advance.  Naturally, I will feel like an idiot when I see what I a doing wrong.

Comment: Side note: `n5.next = (struct entry*)0;` should be written `n5.next = NULL;`

Comment: that certainly looks easier to write and read.  Any othe reason?

Comment: [Is NULL always zero in C?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9894013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use such a call like this

```
insertEntry(&n3_4, &n3);
```

to insert a node before the node `n3` because in this case you need to change the data member `next` of the node `n2` that points to the node `n3`.  But the function has neither information about the node `n2` because you have a singly-linked list.

Even for the call

```
insertEntry(&n0_1, list_pointer);
```

where the pointed node by the pointer list_pointer has no preceding node the function is written incorrectly. At least it should be defined like

```
struct entry * insertEntry(struct entry *what, struct entry *where)
{
    what->next = where;
    where = what;

    return where;
}
```

and called like

```
list_pointer = insertEntry(&n0_1, list_pointer);
```

You can write a function that inserts a new node after a given node. For example

```
struct entry * insertEntry(struct entry *what, struct entry *where)
{
    if ( where == NULL )
    {
        what->next = where;
        where = what;
    }
    else
    {
        what->next = where->next;
        where->next = what;
    }

    return where;
}
```

Comment: More info, from the text "The function developed in exercise 2 only inserts an element after an existing element in the list, thereby preventing you from inserting a new entry at the front of the list.  How can you use the same function and yet overcome this problem (Hint: Think about setting up a special structure to point to the beginning of the list)"                              if the pointer to the list points to the first entry, why can't I insert an entry in between the two?

Comment: @JerrySingh You can insert between two pointers but it means that you have to pass to the function the pointer after which a new pointer will be inserted.  For example if you want to insert the node n3_4 between node n3 and n4 then you have to pass to the function the node n3 bot the node n4.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a step back.

So we have `n1` as the first node, and `list_pointer` is pointing to this first node.

When you insert a node `X` at the beginning of the list, you want `X.next` to point to what `list_pointer` is pointing. So

```
X.next = list_pointer
```

And, this node `X` now becomes your starting node.

```
list_pointer = X
```

Comment: This response was helpful because it clarified my understanding of the mechanics of pointers in a way relevant to my questions.

Answer (score 1):

With the function `insertEntry` shown, you cannot insert anything before the original list pointer. In such a case, the pointer to head of the list would have to change, i.e. the value of `list_pointer` itself needs to change, not the value of `list_pointer.next`; You can follow two approaches:

(1) let the head of the list be always the same (and ignore it's `value`); the first actual item will be the one where `head.next` points to.

(2) change insert entry such it may change the value of `where` (by passing a pointer to that pointer).

Approach (1):

```
struct entry n1, n2, n3, n4, n5,n0_1, n2_3, n3_4, n4_5;
n1.value = 100;
...
struct entry list_pointer;
list_pointer.next = &n1;
...
struct entry* iterator = list_pointer.next;
while (iterator != NULL){
    printf("%i\n", iterator->value);
    iterator = iterator->next;
}
```

Approach (2)

```
void insertBefore(struct entry *what, struct entry **head)
{
    what->next = (*head);  // let what.next point to the former head
    *head = &what;  // let the head-pointer point to the new head
}

insertEntry(&n0_1, &list_pointer);
...
struct entry* iterator = list_pointer;
while (iterator != NULL){
    printf("%i\n", iterator->value);
    iterator = iterator->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sooooo I have been wrestling with this damn thing for awhile.  Here is what I have, which looks pretty good to me.  Where I am lost is how this does not conflict with the answers above?  The list_ptr works as I originally believed it would.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


struct entry
  {
      int      value;
      struct entry *next;
  };

void insertEntry(struct entry *what, struct entry *where)
{
    what->next = where->next;
    where->next = what;
}

void printEntries(struct entry initial)
{
     while (initial.next != NULL){
        printf("%i   \n", initial.next->value);
        initial.next = initial.next->next;
}
printf("\n");
}

int main (void)
{
  struct entry nx2, n0, n1, n2, n3, nx;

  struct entry *list_ptr;

  list_ptr = &n0;

  n1.value = 100;
  n2.value = 200;
  n3.value = 300;

  nx.value = 77;
  nx2.value = 15;

  n0.next = &n1;
  n1.next = &n2;
  n2.next = &n3;
  n3.next = NULL;

    printEntries(*list_ptr);
    insertEntry(&nx, list_ptr);
    printEntries(*list_ptr);
    insertEntry(&nx2, &n2);
    printEntries(n0);



  return 0;
}
```